# Any way to display the duplicated songs in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

I recently upgraded to iTunes 11 *(v 11.0 (163))* and the show duplicate feature has been removed. What tools or alternatives exist to display duplicates in iTunes?

Comment: It's sure well hidden if that feature made it into iTunes 11.0 - it's clearly gone from the help and the menu items.

Comment: Apple’s iTunes 11 Update will Restore Duplicate Song Search: http://amog.com/tech/155375-apples-itunes-11-update-restore-duplicate-song-search/

Comment: You should add that as a real answer and we can edit it to indicate that this is only a problem in iTunes 11.0 so people can see the best answer for the long term... (unless of course you prefer to have the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of applications out there that will do this. The feature in iTunes was never that good anyway since it didn't really let you compare files to make sure you weren't deleting the wrong files (like songs that appear in compilations, best-ofs, etc).

Probably some free options out there, but [Dupe Away](http://www.macroplant.com/dupeaway/) is pretty good ($13). I'm sure some Googling might yield more results

Answer (score 7):

Apple have put the "Show duplicates" function back to iTunes 11. Go to View menu in iTunes and select "Show duplicate items"

A word of caution though, iTunes shows many false duplicates for me, anything with the same track name appears to be shown as duplicate. I much prefer the way [Tune Sweeper](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/tunesweeper/) deals with duplicates, there's no false duplicates and you can choose to keep the highest quality track.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way.  Are you a Microsoft Excel geek??  I am.  Highlight the entire library.  Copy (Ctrl+C).  Paste Special (text) in to an excel sheet.  Next is up to you.  I wanted to look for duplicate song AND album.  So I concatenated the two in a column to the right (formula example is "=C1&E1").  Then in the next column over, use the countif formula to look for duplicates ("=COUNTIF($D$4:$D$5447,D4"). Anywhere the formula returns "2" you know there is a duplicate.  You can use a filter on that column to see them all very easily.  Now the hard part.  You have to go back one by one and delete you dupes.

Comment: Good idea! Works in Numbers or LibreOffice as well

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a cheaper ($0.99) alternative, even though it's not specifically made for the iTunes library but for the whole file system: [Twins Mini](https://itunes.apple.com/app/twins-mini/id540383737?mt=12).

It does work very well and it's pretty fast (analyzing my 140GB library takes about 2 minutes on an early 2009 iMac).